# Filter out results in a collection without removing them from the collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have a filter that filters out items in an `ObservableCollection` so that only certain items in the collection are displayed in my datagrid. The OC is called *MyTruckCollection*.

The only way that I can filter out results is by removing the items that I do not want and only adding the items that I do want. (I cannot hide certain items in the collection)

**Example:**

```
var filteredList = MyTruckCollection.Where(x => x.TruckStatus == filterValue).ToList();
MyTruckCollection.Clear();
foreach (var filteredItem in filteredList)
    MyTruckCollection.Add(filteredItem);
```

Now my issue is that I do not want to remove the items that I do not want from the list, because when I add another filter, the collection only contains the items that was added by the previous filter. So the list of items in my collection is getting smaller and smaller with every filter that I add.

So the question is: Is there a way to filter out certain items in my OC without removing them and still update my datagrid's UI.

I can do this as well:

```
dgMyTruckCollection.ItemSource = MyTruckCollection.Where(x => x.TruckStatus == filterValue);
```

But then I loose access to my collection if I want to apply a *Sorting* function to it and the UI does not get updated. I am not too good with MVVM and do not know much about it, so if someone can help me please?

Comment: you can use a CollectionView (http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html)

Comment: Why you are MyTruckCollection.Clear(); when you want to reuse the collection ?

Comment: @mybirthname Otherwise the items that I add will be added multiple times and I do not want duplicates in the collection. Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Add a FilteredTruckCollection property to the view model and populate this instead of reusing MyTruckCollection

Comment: Use a `Converter` on Visible Property of the items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ICollectionView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) interface for the filtering/sorting task. Would be something like this

```
ICollectionView MyTruckCollectionView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyTruckCollection);
MyTruckCollectionView.Filter = o => ((Truck)o).TruckStatus==filterValue
MyTruckCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("field", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
....
```

Comment: Great thanks the example worked correctly as it should. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make MyTruckCollection a get-only property that applies the active filters when called over a private myTruckCollection that holds all the values.